# How to show uploaded pictures in a Drupal view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm building a website in Drupal. I want to show some information about artistic espectacles including some pictures of it. When i define the fields to show in the corresponding view and i include the images as a content in the Fields section, the corresponding query returns the path to the image and not the image itself which is the wanted behavior. I want to know a way to make a view in Drupal which allows me show the images and not their paths. If the question isn't clear enough, please make me know and i help you to understand. Thank you.

Comment: I notice you haven't accepted any answers on previous. Try going through your previous questions and see which ones have been answered. Then click the checkmark icon next to the posts which answered them.

Comment: Sebastian, i have received comments as yours in the past. The fact is that i'm a nubee here and i don't know what checkmark you are talking about. I don't know if there is some error in my connection (that is very slow cause i live in Cuba) and the page doesn't load well all of te components. Any help from you will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar troubles with Views, but actually desired the behavior you are encountering. So long as you have the image's path, you can write it to the View's output wrapped in HTML `<img>` tags. So for example, `<img src="[image path your view is outputting]" alt="">`. This should display the image for you.

Depending on your Drupal version there are some great add-on modules which make Views more flexible.

[This Views PHP module](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) works for Drupal 7 (I have not personally tested) and allows you to incorporate regular PHP code into Views output.
I have used [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield/) extensively in Drupal 6 and it works great.